Shared Outlook Calendar automation
I am a co-owner of a shared 2019 Outlook calendar. I made a default appointment template with user defined fields on P2 of the template using "Design This Form" under developer options.
This form allows users to enter variables for specific device setup parameters and records utilisation data of that device based on calculations drawn from standard appointment item properties like [Start] and [End] and other user defined fields.
I would like, independent of user action, to periodically send reminder emails to the authors of appointments if certain user defined field conditions within the individual appointment are/are not met based on the current date/time.
The main two issues:
I cannot see where in the Visual Basic project window to host the code as I can only see "This Outlook Session" and "Modules".
I am not able to drill down into the structure to access the values of the user defined properties.
I tried various things like the following, but it seems the VBA code is hosted in my Outlook session and not on the shared calendar server.
Private Sub Application_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

On Error Resume Next
Dim calFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("xxxBookings@exchange.xxx.com")
objOwner.Resolve
       
If objOwner.Resolved Then
'   MsgBox objOwner.Name
    Set newCalFolder = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
End If ' Check if the modified item is an appointment in the specific calendar folder

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then _
Set appt = Item

' Check if the user-defined field condition is met
If appt.UserProperties("OperatorStartTimeText").value = "0000" Or "" Then
' Perform actions based on the condition
' For example, send an email response SendResponseEmail appt
End If
End If
End Sub

